# Workflow to send email alerts if a list item wasn't created by a user after X days?

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, designer-workflow

I created a list on SharePoint 2013 on premise used by many users (80+) to track their milestones by creating a new list item. The users were asking if it's possible to have an email sent out if a user hasn't created a new item over 30 days.

I was wondering if anyone had any ideas on how a workflow can detect if a specific user has created a new l item on the list after 30 days and send them an email afterwards. I find it hard to implement because there are so many users and I can't think of a workflow logic for the workflow to check if a new item was created by the same user in the last 30 days. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This would be very complex, but I think you would need a few workflows and another list to make this happen.
Basically you need a "tracking" list to keep up with who has and has not added an item, 2 columns - "user" - people picker and "has submitted" - Yes / No

When a user adds an item you need a workflow that changes the No value in the tracking list to a Yes value.  Then you need a workflow that runs on the tracking list to send the email - If last modified date is more than 30 days, and "has submitted" = No, then send email or if last modified date is more than 30 days, and "has submitted" = Yes, set "has submitted" to No. Or something like that.

Comment: this was a great idea. thank you!